# Creating multiple columns from one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

My database is structured like this:

```
Number | Month | Country
------------------------
63     | June  | Ireland
48     | June  | England
55     | June  | Spain
66     | May   | Ireland
33     | May   | England
53     | May   | Spain
44     | April | Ireland
44     | April | England
44     | April | Spain
```

I want to use an SQL statement to call this from the data above. Can anyone help me out please. Basically I want to split the number column into multiple other columns according to the month associated with it. I'm using sql-server 2000

```
Country | June | May | April
---------------------------
Ireland | 63   | 66  |  44
England | 48   | 33  |  44
Spain   | 55   | 53  |  44
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That process is called pivoting.  One way to do it:

```
 select  Country
 ,       sum(case when Month = 'June' then Number end) as June
 ,       sum(case when Month = 'May' then Number end) as May
 ,       sum(case when Month = 'April' then Number end) as April
 from    YourTable
 group by
         Country
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this if the number values are nvarchar instead of int values

Comment: Sure, just cast them to int, like `case when Month = 'April' then cast(Number as int) end`

Comment: What if we have more than three month names in the main table?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,Here this query will give the proper results irrespective of the unique number of months.It means there is no need to hard code the months name as column names.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(Number int,Months varchar(10),Country varchar(10))
INSERT INTO tbl1
VALUES(63,'June','Ireland'),
(48,'June','England'),
(55,'June','Spain'),
(66,'May','Ireland'),
(33,'May','England'),
(53,'May','Spain'),
(44,'April','Ireland'),
(44,'April','England'),
(44,'April','Spain')

DECLARE @month_colms varchar(100)
DECLARE @sqlstr varchar(1000)
DECLARE @colname varchar(100)
select @month_colms=STUFF((select ', '+months from (select months from tbl1 group by months) a for xml path('')),1,1,'')
SET @sqlstr=''
While(CHARINDEX(',',@month_colms,1)>0)
BEGIN
SELECT @colname=LEFT(ltrim(rtrim(@month_colms)),CHARINDEX(',',ltrim(rtrim(@month_colms)),1)-1)
SET @month_colms=RIGHT(ltrim(rtrim(@month_colms)),LEN(ltrim(rtrim(@month_colms)))-CHARINDEX(',',ltrim(rtrim(@month_colms)),1))
SET @sqlstr=@sqlstr+','+'sum(case when Months = '''+@colname+''' then Number end) as '''+@colname+''''
END

SET @sqlstr=@sqlstr+','+'sum(case when Months = '''+ltrim(rtrim(@month_colms))+''' then Number end) as '''+@month_colms+''''

exec('select  Country'+@sqlstr+' from tbl1 group by Country')
```