# Transforming a table by the condition in one row

Tags: sql, ms-access, case

I have a table like this

```
Day        Operation       Times Condition
Monday     addition        3     done
Monday     subtraction     2     done
Monday     subtraction     4     uncomplete
Tuesday    multiplication  3     done
Tuesday    addition        1     done
Tuesday    addition        8     uncomplete
Wednesday  subtraction     1     uncomplete
```

And I want to transform the Condition column in two distinct columns something like

```
Day        Operation       Done  Uncomplete Total
Monday     addition        3     0          3
Monday     subtraction     2     4          6
Tuesday    multiplication  3     0          3
Tuesday    addition        1     8          9
Wednesday  subtraction     0     1          1
```

Fusioning the Done and Uncomplete Operations in a single row

Is there a way to do it in SQL?

So far I have tried something like this [Creating multiple columns from one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724953/creating-multiple-columns-from-one-column) using case. I think than I may need to group it first by day, and then by Operation.

Comment: I'm doing this is ACCESS apparently When isn't implemented there

Comment: What you need is a PIVOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the fact that you do this on Microsoft Access please refer to the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgerpTHzQes

Comment: ty very much, I would never find that solution by myself

Answer (score 0):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select day, operation,
       sum(case when condition = 'done' then times else 0 end) as dones,
       sum(case when condition = 'uncomplete' then times else 0 end) as uncompletes,
       sum(times) as total
from t
group by day, operation;
```

You need to tag your question with the database you are using.  The equivalent in MS Access is:

```
select day, operation,
       sum(iif(condition = "done", times, 0))  as dones,
       sum(iif(condition = "uncomplete", times, 0)) as uncompletes,
       sum(times) as total
from t
group by day, operation;
```

Comment: I am  receiving an error, appraently is missing an operator in    sum(case when condition = 'done' then times else 0 end)

Comment: but watching the documentation I can't find the mistake